# How to validate HTML dropdown lists and input fields before clicking the submit button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, validation

This is my question: I have three drop-down lists and two input fields. This is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   
  Name : <input type="text" id="one"/><br/><br/><br/>
  <label for="two">Select category</label>
   <select id="two">
    <option>--select--</option>
    <option>books</option>
    <option>penss</option>
    <option>pensils</option>
    <option>erasers</option>
   </select>
 <br/><br/><br/>
   <label for="three">Select country</label>
    <select id="three">
    <option>--select--</option>
    <option>japan</option>
    <option>canada</option>
    <option>usa</option>
    <option>uk</option>
   </select>
<br/><br/><br/>
   Amount :<input type="text" id="four"/>
<br/><br/><br/>
    <label for="five">Select city</label>
    <select id="five">
    <option>--select--</option>
    <option>ottawa</option>
    <option>washinton</option>
    <option>austin</option>
    <option>texas</option>
   </select>
<br/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

So what I want is to validate like this,

If the user selects any field (input or section) from any place, not selected fields should be validated. They cannot use the submit button. As an example if the user selects the middle selection (countries) and at that time other fields are not selected all should validate on clicking of the select. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code and tell me if this is what you want. I will change it according to your need otherwise.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#two,#three,#five").change(function(){
    var text='';
    
    if($("#one").text() == '') alert('enter in one');
      
    
    text = $("#two").find(":selected").text();
    if(text == '--select--') alert("select two");
    
    text = $("#three").find(":selected").text();
    if(text == '--select--') alert("select three");
    
    if($("#one").text() == '') alert('enter in four');
    
    text = $("#five").find(":selected").text();
    if(text == '--select--') alert("select five");
    
    
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   
  Name : <input type="text" id="one"/><br/><br/><br/>
  <label for="two">Select category</label>
   <select id="two">
    <option>--select--</option>
    <option>books</option>
    <option>penss</option>
    <option>pensils</option>
    <option>erasers</option>
   </select>
 <br/><br/><br/>
   <label for="three">Select country</label>
    <select id="three">
    <option>--select--</option>
    <option>japan</option>
    <option>canada</option>
    <option>usa</option>
    <option>uk</option>
   </select>
<br/><br/><br/>
   Amount :<input type="text" id="four"/>
<br/><br/><br/>
    <label for="five">Select city</label>
    <select id="five">
    <option>--select--</option>
    <option>ottawa</option>
    <option>washinton</option>
    <option>austin</option>
    <option>texas</option>
   </select>
<br/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is nice, but I want to validate input fields also

Answer (score 0):

You have to use change function of dropdown

```
$("#dropdownID" ).change(function() {
     //You can write validate code here...
     alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use value for each option like,

```js
$(function() {
  // bind click event for validation
  $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function() {
    var msg = [];
    $('input[type="text"],select').each(function() {
      if (this.value.trim().length === 0) {
        msg.push('please enter value for: ' + this.id);
      }
    });
    if (msg.length) {
      alert(msg.join("\n"))
    }
  });
  // select on change check value
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    if (!this.value) {
      alert('please select value for: ' + this.id);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  Name :
  <input type="text" id="one" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label for="two">Select category</label>
  <select id="two">
    <option value="">--select--</option>
    <option value="books">books</option>
    <option value="penss">penss</option>
    <option value="pensils">pensils</option>
    <option value="erasers">erasers</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label for="three">Select country</label>
  <select id="three">
    <option value="">--select--</option>
    <option value="japan">japan</option>
    <option value="canada">canada</option>
    <option value="usa">usa</option>
    <option value="uk">uk</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Amount :
  <input type="text" id="four" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label for="five">Select city</label>
  <select id="five">
    <option value="">--select--</option>
    <option value="ottawa">ottawa</option>
    <option value="washinton">washinton</option>
    <option value="austin">austin</option>
    <option value="texas">texas</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
</body>

</html>
```

And you can also try [Jquery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: I don't want to use it in button click